# lateinit property not initialized when Activity is re-created

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

In my Activity I have a `lateinit` property called `controller` that my Fragment uses.
This property is initialized in `Activity.onCreate()`. My `Fragment` gets its reference back to my `Activity` through `onAttach()`. The `Fragment` then calls `myActivity.controller` in `Fragment.onCreate()`.

Normally `controller` is first initialized in `Activity.onCreate()`, and after that, the `Fragment` is added. So this works just fine.

But when my `Activity` has been killed, it tries to recreate itself and its fragments. This causes `Fragment.onCreate()` to be called **before** the initialization took place in `Activity.onCreate()`.

These are the options I see right now:

- initialize `controller` before `super.onCreate()` (if that's even possible)
- move the call to `myActivity.controller` to a later lifecycle callback, as `onViewCreated()`
- something with `::controller.isInitialized` available in Kotlin 1.2

What is my best option here?

Comment: What about using `by lazy { /* initialization code */ }`?

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana this actually fixes the crash in my case, but I don't think this is a general solution to this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reviewing the [`Fragment` lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating), in fact the safest point to do it will be [`#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)).

Even when `#onAttach()` looks like it is called when the `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity`, I'm not sure if this is completely guaranteed, as the old [`#onAttach(android.app.Activity)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)) is deprecated, and the new [`#onAttach(android.content.Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)) is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle such scenario where an object is used before initialization is by checking with isInitialized() property and then using it.